# Buck converter high side switch GND

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, buck, powermosfet, high-side

In Figure 1, I designed a synchronous buck converter using the IR2110S half bridge gate driver integration. However, when I look at the source-GND measurements of the high side MOSFETs in Figure 2, I see that the voltages don’t reach zero. Why could such a situation occur?

Thanks.
Figure 1
[image]
Figure 2
[image]
Edit
Output voltage 35V and 105W.
MOSFET = IXTP90N15T
Input voltage = 60V
Full schematic
[image]

Comment: 1 mV off, 10 mV off, 100 mV etc... what load were you using and what power supply voltage for the 2110 and the top MOSFET? What MOSFETs and where are the data sheet links? Also show exactly how and where you were probing on the circuit. Show those points on the schematic too.

Comment: *source-GND* Huh? You mean **the source of M1** or pin 5 (VS) of the IR2110. What needs to pull that node to GND? M2! So check that M2 turns fully on, measure its Vgs and Vds.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, I measurement Vs pin to GND in other word switchnode of the buck converter. The result I showed on the oscilloscope is already equal to the Vds of the M2 Mosfet.

Comment: @Andyaka I have edit the post.

Comment: M1 and M2 seem both to have Vds several volts in the ON-state. It seems that either you have too low Vgs drive voltages or there's  too much load current.